# How to capture the entire usercontrol even if it is outside the bounds of the application

Tags: c#, wpf

Currently I am working on a WPF application and I have a task to take a screenshot of a UserControl containing some charts.
How I do it now:

```
var pixelWidth = Convert.ToInt32(userControl.RenderSize.Width);
var pixelHeight = Convert.ToInt32(userControl.RenderSize.Height);
RenderTargetBitmap renderTargetBitmap =
    new RenderTargetBitmap(pixelWidth, pixelHeight, 96, 96, PixelFormats.Default);
renderTargetBitmap.Render(userControl);
PngBitmapEncoder pngImage = new PngBitmapEncoder();
pngImage.Frames.Add(BitmapFrame.Create(renderTargetBitmap));

SaveFileDialog dlg = new SaveFileDialog
{
    DefaultExt = "png",
    Filter = "Png Files|*.png"
};

if (dlg.ShowDialog() == true)
{
    using (Stream fileStream = File.Create(dlg.FileName))
    {
        pngImage.Save(fileStream);
    }
}
```

This approach works if the UserControl is entirely visible in my app.

However, there are cases when the charts are no longer fully visible, and then you have to go full screen to capture correctly the entire UserControl.

My question: is there a way to capture the entire UserControl without going full screen?

Comment: You could create a new, identical one and capture that instead of the existing one. As long as you make sure it has passed at least one layout cycle (e.g. by manually calling Measure and Arrange) it doesn't have to be on-screen.

Comment: Even with the original control it might be worth to call `Measure` and `Arrange` with the desired size before rendering and `UpdateLayout` after rendering

Comment: I cannot copy the entire content, it is a live chart. I've tried the second approach, by calling measure and arrange and after rendering updatelayout, but not luck.